# Help Getting Two NICs On Same Machine Talking Via Switch

Tags: networking, 14.04, hyper-v, nic

I have a virtual Ubuntu Server (14.04) VM on Hyper-V host with three NICs
 - eth0 is bridged to the external network
 - eth1 & eth2 are attached to a private virtual switch

The aim is to get the VM to communicate with itself using eth1 and eth2 whilst traffic is still being sent via the switch - so it can then be forwarded/sniffed

I believe I have set up the correct settings for each interface and have also followed the post here - [Set up two IP addresses with one gateway?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315166/set-up-two-ip-addresses-with-one-gateway)

When I try to ping from one interface to the other tcpdump shows the ARP request coming to the other interface but they are never responded to:

$ ping -b -I eth1 10.0.0.6

```
PING 10.0.0.6 (10.0.0.6) from 10.0.0.5 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.5 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.0.0.6 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6018ms
pipe 4
```

$ tcpdump -i eth2

```
21:27:19.666738 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.6 tell 10.0.0.5, length 28
21:27:20.666636 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.6 tell 10.0.0.5, length 28
...
```

I can ping to/from other devices on the virtual switch...

What's even more peculiar is that I can SSH to either interface from the other, the traffic of which does not show up on tcpdump.

$ ssh -i eth1 root@10.0.0.6

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Some extra info:

$ ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:0e:f9:09
          inet addr:172.16.33.225  Bcast:172.16.39.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe0e:f909/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:480545 errors:0 dropped:7810 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:50354580 (50.3 MB)  TX bytes:1754707 (1.7 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:0e:f9:0a
          inet addr:10.0.0.5  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe0e:f90a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:506 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:9293 (9.2 KB)  TX bytes:100827 (100.8 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:0e:f9:0b
          inet addr:10.0.0.6  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe0e:f90b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:347 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:88 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20373 (20.3 KB)  TX bytes:6448 (6.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5523 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2173284 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:2173284 (2.1 MB)
```

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.16.33.225
        netmask 255.255.248.0
        ...

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.5
        network 10.0.0.0
        netmask 255.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.255.255.255
        up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 src 10.0.0.5 table eth1table
        up ip route add default via 0.0.0.0 dev eth1 table eth1table
        up ip rule add from 10.0.0.5 table eth1table
        up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth1 src 10.0.0.5

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 10.0.0.6
        network 10.0.0.0
        netmask 255.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.255.255.255
        up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth2 src 10.0.0.6 table eth2table
        up ip route add default via 0.0.0.0 dev eth2 table eth2table
        up ip rule add from 10.0.0.6 table eth2table
        up ip route add default via 0.0.0.0 dev eth2
        up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth2 src 10.0.0.6
```

Any help is appreciated guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible: packets destined for the local machine are processed by the local machine, not forwarded.